# what determines overburn capability of CD-R?

Tags: data-cd, burning

I had a 733MiB ISO image which I tried to write to a CD-R. I had two CD-R disks from different manufacturers. With first CD-R disk(TDK) the burning process failed, but using the second CD-R(EMTEC), it succeeded. Command used for burning was `wodim -v speed=1 dev='/dev/scd0' -sao -overburn /home/martin/Downloads/linux.iso`

*Unsuccessful attempt:*

```
root@T42:~# ls -lh /home/martin/Downloads/linux.iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 martin martin 733M Feb  7 19:30 /home/martin/Downloads/linux.iso
root@T42:~# wodim -v speed=1 dev='/dev/scd0' -sao -overburn /home/martin/Downloads/linux.iso
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
scsidev: '/dev/scd0'
devname: '/dev/scd0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVDRAM GSA-4083N'
Revision       : '1.00'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x0009 (CD-R)
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) (current)
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Drive buf size : 1053696 = 1029 KB
Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
Drive DMA Speed: 15251 kB/s 86x CD 11x DVD
FIFO size      : 12582912 = 12288 KB
Track 01: data   732 MB        
Total size:      840 MB (83:17.54) = 374816 sectors
Lout start:      841 MB (83:19/41) = 374816 sectors
Current Secsize: 2048
ATIP info from disk:
  Indicated writing power: 5
  Is not unrestricted
  Is not erasable
  Disk sub type: Medium Type B, low Beta category (B-) (4)
  ATIP start of lead in:  -12369 (97:17/06)
  ATIP start of lead out: 359849 (79:59/74)
Disk type:    Short strategy type (Phthalocyanine or similar)
Manuf. index: 69
Manufacturer: Moser Baer India Limited
Manufacturer is guessed because of the orange forum embargo.
The orange forum likes to get money for recent information.
The information for this media may not be correct.
Blocks total: 359849 Blocks current: 359849 Blocks remaining: -14967
wodim: WARNING: Data may not fit on current disk.
wodim: Notice: Overburning active. Trying to write more than the official disk capacity.
Speed set to 1764 KB/s
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  10.0 in real SAO mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... input buffer ready.
Performing OPC...
Sending CUE sheet...
Writing pregap for track 1 at -150
Starting new track at sector: 0
Track 01:  724 of  732 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  10.7x.Errno: 5 (Input/output error), write_g1 scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  2A 00 00 05 A9 9D 00 00 1F 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 3C 30 00 80 02 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x02 Qual 0x00 (no seek complete) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 26.366s timeout 200s

write track data: error after 760014848 bytes
wodim: A write error occured.
wodim: Please properly read the error message above.
Writing  time:  549.691s
Average write speed   9.1x.
Min drive buffer fill was 99%
Fixating...
Fixating time:    0.183s
wodim: fifo had 12091 puts and 11972 gets.
wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 11841 times full, min fill was 96%.
root@T42:~#
```

*Successful attempt:*

```
root@T42:~# wodim -v speed=1 dev='/dev/scd0' -sao -overburn /home/martin/Downloads/linux.iso
    TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
    scsidev: '/dev/scd0'
    devname: '/dev/scd0'
    scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
    Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
    Wodim version: 1.1.11
    SCSI buffer size: 64512
    Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
    Version        : 5
    Response Format: 2
    Capabilities   : 
    Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
    Identification : 'DVDRAM GSA-4083N'
    Revision       : '1.00'
    Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
    Current: 0x0009 (CD-R)
    Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
    Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
    Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
    Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
    Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
    Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
    Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
    Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
    Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
    Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
    Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) (current)
    Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
    Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
    Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
    Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
    Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
    Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
    Drive buf size : 1053696 = 1029 KB
    Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
    communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
    Drive DMA Speed: 15143 kB/s 86x CD 10x DVD
    FIFO size      : 12582912 = 12288 KB
    Track 01: data   732 MB        
    Total size:      840 MB (83:17.54) = 374816 sectors
    Lout start:      841 MB (83:19/41) = 374816 sectors
    Current Secsize: 2048
    ATIP info from disk:
      Indicated writing power: 5
      Is not unrestricted
      Is not erasable
      Disk sub type: Medium Type A, high Beta category (A+) (3)
      ATIP start of lead in:  -11634 (97:26/66)
      ATIP start of lead out: 359846 (79:59/71)
    Disk type:    Short strategy type (Phthalocyanine or similar)
    Manuf. index: 3
    Manufacturer: CMC Magnetics Corporation
    Blocks total: 359846 Blocks current: 359846 Blocks remaining: -14970
    wodim: WARNING: Data may not fit on current disk.
    wodim: Notice: Overburning active. Trying to write more than the official disk capacity.
    Speed set to 1764 KB/s
    Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  10.0 in real SAO mode for single session.
    Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
    Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... input buffer ready.
    Performing OPC...
    Sending CUE sheet...
    Writing pregap for track 1 at -150
    Starting new track at sector: 0
    Track 01:  732 of  732 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf  99%]  10.6x.
    Track 01: Total bytes read/written: 767623168/767623168 (374816 sectors).
    Writing  time:  520.286s
    Average write speed   9.6x.
    Min drive buffer fill was 99%
    Fixating...
    Fixating time:    4.733s
    wodim: fifo had 12091 puts and 12091 gets.
    wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 11889 times full, min fill was 96%.
    root@T42:~#
```

Does the overburn capability depends solely on CD-R/CD-RW lead-out are size? In addition, any ideas what the *"low Beta category (B-) (4)"* and *"high Beta category (A+) (3)"* mean in CD-R ATIP info section?

Answer (score 4):

The original CD data storage size was 650 MiB; these are also called 74 minute CDs, since that's the amount of audio data you can get into the same space. Well after CD-Rs started becoming available, you started seeing 700 MiB (or 80 minute) CD-Rs. Most CD-Rs sold these days are of this newer sort.

I've never seen a CD-R capable of holding 733 MiB, and [the first page of Amazon results for "CD-R"](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&keywords=cd-r) doesn't show any that big.

It may just be blind luck that allowed that image to burn at all. Or, it might not have burned correctly after all. If your OS installer has a media verification feature, you should definitely use it the first time you install from that overburnt disc.

That image may not be intended for CD-Rs at all. The ISO CD format is lately becoming popular for USB key images. There are tools like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) for this very purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Warren Young may have not known this in 2013, but Mediarange manufactures CD-R disks designed to accept 90 minutes of music (800MB) or 100 minutes of music (900MB), but you have to use a special overburn feature in your burning software. Back in the days, Nero was popular software.

Now, in 2019, as I am installing my new computer, looking for my same old software, I get frowned at when I explain how I would like to burn music on CD-R disks, to use them in my car. People suggest I should come up with USB-sticks, or stream music through mobile internet.

Well, I have tried, but a USB-stick in a car looses track of the album I was listening to when I interrupt the electricity, even just to start the engine. Mobile internet costs more money then the €10 I spend on my prepaid phone for half a year. So call me old fashioned, if you want, but please respect my free choice! ;-)

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting perspective on things, but I don't see how it answers the original question "what determines overburn capability of CD-R on UNIX/Linux?". Generally, on-topic answers are most appreciated here.